# How can I calculate cosine similarity between first row of my matrix with each other rows in R?

Tags: r, matrix, cosine-similarity

this is my_matrix :

```
ui 194635691 194153563 177382028 177382031 195129144 196972549 196258704   194907960 196950156 194139014 153444738 192982501 192891196
1 237      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00         0      0.01         0         0         0         0         0
2 261      0.01      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00         0      0.00         0         0         0         0         0
3 290      0.00      0.00      0.01      0.01      0.00      0.00         0      0.00         0         0         0         0         0
4 483      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.01         0      0.00         0         0         0         0         0
5 533      0.00      0.01      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00         0      0.00         0         0         0         0         0
6 534      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.01      0.00         0      0.00         0         0         0         0         0
```

these are my codes are following:

```
b=my_matrix[1,2:length(my_matrix)]

for (i in nrow(my_matrix)) {
 res[i]=cosine(b,my_matrix[i,2:length(my_matrix)])
}
```

I used "lsa" package and
I want to get a cosine similarity matrix that calculate b vector with every other vectors from matrix a  but my codes throw a error that says :

```
argument mismatch. Either one matrix or two vectors needed as input.
```

What Should I do to fix my problem?
many thanks in advance

Comment: Who is `a`? What is `cosine` and from which package it comes from?

Comment: When I try `b=my_matrix[1,2:length(my_matrix)]` I get an error. Do you meant `ncol` instead of `length`? Is `my_matrix` a `matrix` or a `data.frame`?

Comment: The `ISA` package has been removed from `CRAN`. I found an 8 year old github repository. Either I didn't find the right package or you should find more recent tools.

Comment: @nicola https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lsa/

Comment: @nicola my_matrix is a data.frame I didnt know its make a difference

Answer (score 3):

Package "isa", which is not available for R version 3.2.2, is not really necessary. Just do it yourself, using the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) of cosine similarity:

```
my_matrix <- as.matrix(my_matrix)  # Make sure that "my_matrix" is indeed a "matrix".
v <- as.vector(my_matrix[1,-1])
M <- my_matrix[-1,-1]
cosSim <- ( M %*% v ) / sqrt( sum(v*v) * rowSums(M*M) )
```

The first line is only necessary if `my_matrix` is not yet a `matrix` but a `data.frame`.

*A possible explanation for the original error message shown in the question:*

I guess the class of the object `my_matrix` that was used in the code presented in the question and caused the error message

> argument mismatch. Either one matrix or two vectors needed as input.

was `data.frame`, not a `matrix`. If so, the arguments `b` and `my_matrix[i,2:length(my_matrix)]` in the call of the `cosine` function are again data.frames, not a vector and a matrix as exspected.

*As an aside:*

Even if `my_matrix` is coerced to a `matrix` the code in the question will throw an error massage, since `length(my_matrix)` is larger than the number of columns and hence `my_matrix[i,2:length(my_matrix)]` selects undefined columns.
The `i`-th row of `my_matrix` without the first column is `my_matrix[i,2:ncol(my_matrix)]` or shorter `my_matrix[i,-1]`.

Comment: @mra68 I have just tryed your codes and got an error while doing this multiplication   ( M %*% v ) Any thoughts?

Comment: What was the error message? Did you use the matrix shown in your question? If not, edit your question please.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this:

```
A <- my_matrix[, -1]
b <- A[1,]
res <- apply(A[-1, ], 1, cosine, y=b)
```

This code was executed without an error:

```
d <- read.table(skip=1, text="ui 194635691 194153563 177382028 177382031 195129144 196972549 196258704   194907960 196950156 194139014 153444738 192982501 192891196
1 237      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00         0      0.01         0         0         0         0         0
2 261      0.01      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00         0      0.00         0         0         0         0         0
3 290      0.00      0.00      0.01      0.01      0.00      0.00         0      0.00         0         0         0         0         0
4 483      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.01         0      0.00         0         0         0         0         0
5 533      0.00      0.01      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00         0      0.00         0         0         0         0         0
6 534      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.01      0.00         0      0.00         0         0         0         0         0")

my_matrix <- as.matrix(d)[,-1]  # without rownumbers.

library(lsa)
A <- my_matrix[, -1]  
b <- A[1,]
res <- apply(A[-1, ], 1, cosine, y=b)
```

But the result is vector with all values 0 (i.e. the first row is orthognal to the others). That depends on your data and is easily seen in this case.

Comment: I m still getting same error that is  argument mismatch. Either one matrix or two vectors needed as input.

Answer (score 2):

The cosine function from the [lsa](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lsa/) package calculates the cosine measure between all column vectors of a matrix, therefore:

```
cosine(t(my_matrix[,2:ncol(my_matrix)]))
```

will return a matrix in which the first column is the vector of cosine measures between the first data row of my_matrix (b in your example) and all other rows.

If just want the vector of cosine similarities for the first row:

```
as.vector(cosine(t(my_matrix[,2:ncol(my_matrix)]))[,1])
```

The nth element of this vector is the cosine similarity between the first row and the nth row of the original matrix.

Comment: I m getting this when I run your second code block                                      [1] 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  could u explain to me what is indicates your vector's element. I want to get one column matrix and 1.st row of this matrix should gives us cosine similarity between 1. row and 2. row the second row should give us cosine similarity between 1.row and 3.row and its goes on like this.Many thanks in advance

Comment: Since it's a one column matrix it makes more sense to convert it to a vector. That's what the `as.vector` in the last line of code does. The nth element of this vector is the cosine similarity between the first row and the nth row of the original matrix. In other words: the first element is 1 and it the cosine measure between the first row and itself. The second element is 0, and it's the cosine similarity between the 1st row and the 2nd row. And so on for all rows.

Answer (score 1):

Let **v** be your 1 × m vector and **M** your m × n matrix

```
for (i in 1:dim(M)[2]){
  sim_cos_v[i] <- (v%*%as.vector(M[,i])) / (norm(as.matrix(v), "f")*norm(as.matrix(M[,i]), "f"))
}
sim_cos_v
```